# pass dynamic value in the sed command in unix inside IT block ruby

Tags: ruby, sed

output.txt:

```
select * from table startTime.... (very big query)
```

abc.rb:

```
it "example" do
time = 6537290102
replacestarttime = `sed -i -e 's/startTime/$time/g' ./db/output.txt`
end
```

expected output----
output.txt:

```
select * from table 6537290102....
```

In output.txt, the value should be 6537290102 please someone help. thanks in advance

If I hardcode the time value as shown below in sed command then it is working fine whereas the passing the dynamic value "time" is not working
replacestarttime = `sed -i -e 's/startTime/6537290102/g' ./db/output.txt`

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question. But sorry this is not that clear, kindly do edit your sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Thank you for editing Lavanya, sorry its still not clear by which logic you want to achieve your shown expected output, kindly do add more details in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Using sed commands or any logic .. In output.txt file I should change the startTime to epoch timestamp(653790102 something like above) using ruby automation

Comment: Your problem is probably not sed but [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Comment: could you please provide me the command

Answer (score 3):

Replace single quotes with double quotes

```
`sed -i -e "s/startTime/$time/g" ./db/output.txt`
```

Answer (score 1):

### Interpolate Your String in Ruby

Right now, you're expecting sed to access a shell variable named *$time*. This variable doesn't exist, and wouldn't work as-is even if it did.

To fix this, you should to *interpolate* your Ruby variable into the string passed to sed. You can do this as follows:

```
it "example" do
  time = 6537290102
  replacestarttime = `sed -i -e 's/startTime/#{time}/g' ./db/output.txt`
end
```

Comment: while executing "bundle exec rake " command , I could see this error "sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated `s' command"